# Using a loop to create variables in c#

Tags: c#, loops, variables, uwp

I am creating an app that measures the time a person has gazed at around 300 objects. For all of the objects, it needs to output the time into a text file. I've succesfully coded this for just one object, but I am trying to do it for 300 objects. This is the code I have created for one object:

```
Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();
        gazeButtonControl1 = GazeInput.GetGazeElement(GazeBlock1);
        gazeButtonControl1 = new GazeElement();
        GazeInput.SetGazeElement(GazeBlock1, gazeButtonControl1);
        TimeSpan Word1 = TimeSpan.Zero;
        gazeButtonControl1.StateChanged += GazeBlockControl1_StateChanged;
        void GazeBlockControl1_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs ea)
        {
            if (ea.PointerState == PointerState.Enter)
            {
                Timer.Start();

            }


            if (ea.PointerState == PointerState.Exit)
            {
                Timer.Stop();
                Word1 += Timer.Elapsed;
                File.WriteAllText(@"*insert path here", Word1.ToString());
                Timer.Reset();
            }
        }
```

Everytime there is a "1" inserted in the variable or name of an element, I want to have that for all of the 300 objects. This is what I am looking for:

```
Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            gazeButtonControl[i] = GazeInput.GetGazeElement(GazeBlock[i]);
            gazeButtonControl[i] = new GazeElement();
            GazeInput.SetGazeElement(GazeBlock[i], gazeButtonControl[i]);
            TimeSpan Word[i] = TimeSpan.Zero;
            gazeButtonControl[i].StateChanged += GazeBlockControl[i]_StateChanged;
            void GazeBlockControl[i]_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs ea)
            {
                if (ea.PointerState == PointerState.Enter)
                {
                    Timer.Start();

                }


                if (ea.PointerState == PointerState.Exit)
                {
                    Timer.Stop();
                    Woord[i] += Timer.Elapsed;
                    File.WriteAllText(@"*insert path here", Word[i].ToString());
                    Timer.Reset();
                }
            }
        }
```

This code doesn't work. I've tried using lists and that didn't work either. Does anyone know how to make this solution work? Thanks in advance!

Vincent

Comment: Why don't you move your `StateChanged` handler out of the loop and send the value of `i` in as event args? There's no way that even compiles.

Comment: You only need one StateChanged handler (which should be moved out of the loop) as the `sender` parameter will contain the control whose state changes. Then using `gazeButtonControl.IndexOf((GazeElement)sender)` will return the index of the control which you can then use for your `Word` list. Also I guess you would also need a list of 300 timers - one for each control - instead of only one timer.

Comment: thanks both of you for letting me know I can remove the statechanged handler out of the loop. But I got two questions: what do you mean with gazeButtonControl.IndexOf((GazeElement)sender) ? I am not really familiar with it as I dont have a lot of experience with coding. Second question: In the brackets of GazeInput.GetGazeElement(GazeBlock[i]) there needs to be an UIElement stated. The names of the UIElements in my XAML page (it's an UWP app) are as followed: GazeBlock1, GazeBlock2, GazeBlock3, etc. How do I create a loop that basically counts to 300, and it will replace the [i] value? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use placeholders or array indices in names of variables, methods, and so on.

For UWP there seems to be a helper method `FindChildByName` which allows you to find a control by its name, via `(TypeOfChildControl)insertParentControlHere.FindChildByName("<Name of child control>")`.

I find the following code of yours perplexing:

```
gazeButtonControl1 = GazeInput.GetGazeElement(GazeBlock1);
gazeButtonControl1 = new GazeElement();
GazeInput.SetGazeElement(GazeBlock1, gazeButtonControl1);
```

Basically, first you get your `gazeButtonControl1` from `GazeBlock1` and then ignore it to create a new `GazeElement`. I guess what is meant is something like [in this UWP Gaze sample](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/GazeInteraction/GazeInteractionPage.xaml.cs) where it's first checked if the UI control has a gaze element and if not one is created. So I think it should be:

```
gazeButtonControl1 = GazeInput.GetGazeElement(GazeBlock1);
if (gazeButtonControl1 == null)
{
  gazeButtonControl1 = new GazeElement();
  GazeInput.SetGazeElement(GazeBlock1, gazeButtonControl1);
}
```

Also like i wrote in my initial comment you probably need a separate timer for each gaze element.

So in total it should be something like this (albeit untested):

```
public class YourClass
{
  private TimeSpan[] Word = new TimeSpan[300];
  private Stopwatch[] Timer = new Stopwatch[300];
  private GazeElement[] gazeButtonControl = new GazeElement[300];

  public YourMethod(...)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
      // first find gaze block where parentControl is the control containing your gaze blocks.
      var gazeBlock = (UIElement)parentControl.FindChildByName("GazeBlock" + (i + 1));

      gazeButtonControl[i] = GazeInput.GetGazeElement(gazeBlock);
      if (gazeButtonControl[i] == null)
      {
        gazeButtonControl[i] = new GazeElement();
        GazeInput.SetGazeElement(gazeBlock, gazeButtonControl[i]);
      }

      Word[i] = TimeSpan.Zero;
      Timer[i] = new Stopwatch();
      gazeButtonControl[i].StateChanged += GazeBlockControl_StateChanged;
    }
  }

  private void GazeBlockControl_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs ea)
  {
    // get the GazeElement for which this event was raised
    var changedControl = (GazeElement)sender;
    // find its index in your list of GazeElements.
    var i = Array.IndexOf(gazeButtonControl, changedControl); 

    if (ea.PointerState == PointerState.Enter)
    {
      Timer[i].Start();
    }

    if (ea.PointerState == PointerState.Exit)
    {
      Timer[i].Stop();
      Word[i] += Timer.Elapsed;
      File.WriteAllText(@"*insert path here", Word[i].ToString());
      Timer[i].Reset();
    }
  }
}
```

Please not that I use `Array.IndexOf` instead of `gazeButtonControl.IndexOf` because I declared gazeButtonControl as an array. If it would be a list (e.g. `List<GazeElement> gazeButtonControl`) you would use `gazeButtonControl.IndexOf`.

Comment: Wow! I cannot thank you enough! Thank you so much for helping me solve this, I've been staring at this problem for hours. So I used this code in my app and it all looks fine at first, but when I launch it, i get this error: System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: I have searched for atleast an hour to find the solution to this, and I came to the conclusion that it is different for each case. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Vincent An AccessViolationException generally only happens when native/non-managed code is used, i.e. usually when non-C# code is called. So it’s not directly caused by the code post here and if then maybe by the Gaze control itself. As you said this exception is hard to track. Thus to find the cause you should create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to pinpoint the cause and then post a new question with it on how to solve this issue.

Comment: So after awhile I noticed that I changed the FindChildByName to just FindName and that is causing the issue. To be honest, I did that because I did not understand what you meant with: "first find gaze block where parentControl is the control containing your gaze blocks." Could you explain this a little further? And again: many thanks for helping me out, you have no idea how much I value this ;)

Comment: @Vincent Your GazeBlock1 to GazeBlock300 controls have some kind of parent control they are contained in as you surely have put your GazeBlocks somewhere in your view/XAML file. The parent control is the control which all these GazeBlocks are part of. So either put the name of this parent control where I wrote `parentControl` or alternatively replace `parentControl` by `GazeBlock1.Parent`.